# Serialize javax.ws.rs Entity to json

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I want to serizalize to Json with `org.glassfish.jersey` implementation

```
Map<String, String> entity = Maps.newHashMap();
entity.put("foo", "bar");

Response response = Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                            .entity(entity)
                            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();

System.out.println(response.getEntity());
```

This map serialize to non standard `{ foo: "bar" }`. I want to test this behaviour in unit test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't test like this. What you are doing here

```
Response response = Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                            .entity(entity)
                            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```

is building an **outbound** response. In the JAX-RS framework, after we send out a response, e.g.

```
@GET
@Produced(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getResponse() {
    ...
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                    .entity(entity)
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

it still needs to through a [`MessageBodyWriter`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.9/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) for the serialization to JSON.

- Read more about [Entity Providers](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html)

That being said, Jersey has a [Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html), we can use to test our resource methods. You can find all the official examples [at the Github](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/test-framework/providers)

**A sample (with a few alterations):**

These are the minimum required Maven dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Test class

```
public class TestJSONResource extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
        return new GrizzlyTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Path("test")
    public static class TestResource {
        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response getJson() {
            Map<String, String> entity = Maps.newHashMap();
            entity.put("foo", "bar");

            Response response = Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                    .entity(entity)
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
            return response;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
        return DeploymentContext.builder(new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class))
                .contextPath("context1/context2")
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet() {
        final WebTarget target = target("test");
        final String s = target.request().get(String.class);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

`jersey-media-json-jackson` provides the `MessageBodyWriter` and `MessageBodyReader` for processing JSON, which is implicitly registered for us.

Comment: Thanks, grizzly2 provider return standard `{ "foo": "bar" }` instead of my `{ foo: "bar" }`

Comment: Jersey 2.6 My code example won't even compile. If you want further help, you need to include more information in your post in order for us to help you, i.e. a complete example (with dependencies) that produces the problem. `InternalServerErrorException` server error could mean anything

Comment: More about `InternalServerException`: https://gist.github.com/mariuszs/d859481077f0b0112caa . You are right, without complete (or more concrete) example this is impossible to help me. Thanks again.

Comment: It appears the provider doesn't auto configure itself with 2.6. Using your test, configuring it works `new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class).register(JacksonJsonProvider.class)`

Comment: Or `register(JacksonFeature.class)`