# Sending JSON response with HTTP Status with custom objects

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Before you guys point out, I have already tried this solutions

[Serialize javax.ws.rs Entity to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091834/howto-serialize-javax-ws-rs-entity-to-json)

and it didn't work. Here is how I am trying to send the response:

```
return Response.status(fe.getHttpError())
            .entity(fe)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .build();
```

Where `fe` is an object of type `FirstException`

```
public class FlightException extends Exception {
    private int httpError;
    private int errorCode;
    private String message;

    public FirstException(int httpError, int errorCode, String message) {
        this.httpError = httpError;
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getHttpError() {
        return httpError;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

My maven already have following entry

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

So the question is that how can I send a Response object with HTTP Error code, with custom entity in JSON?

As a side note, if I change this entry to the Glassfish entries from the link I posted earlier, I get following error at startup:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:662)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the status code will be available in the response headers, which i think you already know that. If for some reason you need to send the http status code in the response object, then you have to create an custom Response Wrapper object, which can contain errors as well as response data,

For example, you could do something like,

```
public class ApiResponse implements Serializable  {

    private List<FirstException> errors;

    private Map<String, Object> data; 
}
```

then when you can return failure response like

```
{
"errors": [
  {
  "httpError": 401,
  "errorCode": 401,
  "message": "unauthroized request"
  }
 ]
}
```

and success response like,

```
{
"data": {
  "user": {
   "name": "test"
  }
 }
}
```

this format is also aligned with the standard json api format, checkout http://jsonapi.org/

Comment: this didn't help. I still have the same issue

Comment: Then can you rephrase what you needed . You want to send http status code in response  , I believe this does it , explain you what need or what issues exactly you are facing

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, it is not returning json with http status. It is giving me the same problem that I had earlier.

Comment: Okay , add the code which resource you are using it, because I see you just added exception , so update with the code where you are returning the response you mentioned

Comment: I have alraedy added the code .... here is it again ... `return Response.status(fe.getHttpError())
            .entity(fe)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .build();`

Comment: sorry to say its not helpful, i get this is how you are returning, by where you are returning this line makes a whole lot of sense. here is why, you could return this response from resource endpoints, or exception mappers or even filters, so i still don't get what you are looking for, sorry i couldn't able to help.

Comment: I am not sure whats so hard to understand. The requirement is simple ... I need to return a JSON response with HTTP Status code in Response Header. Now the JSON object which i am passing to to Response object isn't being parsed. It is not converting into String.

Comment: uh see just now you are mentioning that the actual problem is that the Response is not serialized, please read your data again to see if you mentioned this, thanks anyways

Comment: So the question is that how can I send a **Response object with HTTP Error code**, with custom entity in JSON? 

copied from original. Open your eyes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110045/discussion-between-em-ae-and-ramesh).