# Deserializing java.ws.rs Entity using Jackson and Jersey throws exception

Tags: java, jackson, jersey

Building off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27092728/10266770), I've built a simple project to test sending a JSON-serialized POJO as a response to an HTTP request, using Jersey. However, I'm having trouble extracting the POJO out of the response at the other end.

Here's my Jackson-compatible POJO for sending:

```
public class BoringObject {
    private int val;

    //empty constructor for Jackson
    public BoringObject() {}

    public BoringObject(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

Here's the test class that uses Jersey's test framework to try out sending and receiving the POJO:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.DeploymentContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerFactory;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;


public class TestSendBoringObject extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
        return new GrizzlyTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
        return DeploymentContext.builder(new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class))
                .contextPath("context1/context2")
                .build();
    }

    @Path("test")
    public static class TestResource {
        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response getJson() {
            Response response = Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                    .entity(Entity.json(new BoringObject(5)))
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
            return response;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet() {
        final WebTarget target = target("test");
        Response response = target.request().get();
        Entity<BoringObject> entity = response.readEntity(Entity.class);
        BoringObject boringObj = entity.getEntity();
        assertEquals(5, boringObj.getVal());
    }
}
```

However, when I run this test, the `response.readEntity(Entity.class)` call throws the following exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error reading entity from input stream.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:889)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:808)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:321)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse$1.call(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:229)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.runInScopeIfPossible(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:112)
    at TestSendBoringObject.testGet(TestSendBoringObject.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of javax.ws.rs.client.Entity: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@c4ed84; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:1456)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1012)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1206)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1583)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:964)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:257)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1091)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
    ... 41 more
```

Here's my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.mine</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Why am I getting this exception? Have I failed to properly configure Jackson somehow? I'm especially confused that it manages to serialize and send the Entity just fine, but dies when I try to deserialize it. I'm still new to Jersey, so I've probably screwed up something basic. Help is greatly appreciated!

**Edited, more information:**
If I try `readEntity(BoringObject.class)` instead, I get an exception that boils down to "this is not a serialized BoringObject":

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "entity" (class BoringObject), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "val"])
at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@40844aab; line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: BoringObject["entity"])
```

I think this is because I've wrapped the `BoringObject` in a `Entity.json()` call while placing it into the response. (I've done this because that's what the real code that I'm trying to debug with this experiment is doing).

If I do `readEntity(String.class)`, I get the following, which I figured was a serialized `Entity` object, hence my `readEntity(Entity.class)` attempt:

```
{
    "entity": {
        "val": 5
    },
    "variant": {
        "language": null,
        "mediaType": {
            "type": "application",
            "subtype": "json",
            "parameters": {

            },
            "wildcardSubtype": false,
            "wildcardType": false
        },
        "encoding": null,
        "languageString": null
    },
    "annotations": [],
    "language": null,
    "encoding": null,
    "mediaType": {
        "type": "application",
        "subtype": "json",
        "parameters": {

        },
        "wildcardSubtype": false,
        "wildcardType": false
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not supposed to use `Entity` in `readEntity()`, you should use your custom type for that. It it is not working, you might need to add a no-arg constructor. `readEntity(BoringObject.class)`.

Comment: Hi, @PaulSamsotha, thanks for your response! Your original post that I linked really helped me get unstuck on how to debug this problem!

Comment: I added more info to my question about what happens when I try `readEntity(BoringObject.class)`. Also, `BoringObject` already has a no-arg constructor -- or did you mean something else?

Comment: Don't use Entity.json on the server. Just use the object,

Comment: Ah-ha, yep, that was the problem. I thought I needed the `Entity.json` call to make sure the content got marked as `application/json`, but the `type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` call was already doing that. Thanks!